# How are players matched when creating a new town?

Tags: die2nite

I ask because in my first town there were a couple of people with experience, and the rest were almost entirely new. My second town again had a couple of people with experience, and the rest had been in 1-3 towns before.

Is there some mysterious skill assessment going on that ensures the people I'm working with will be steadily more mature? (please say yes)

Comment: Please clarify what game you mean in your question.

Comment: @Tim Holt: Die2Nite. Is tagging insufficient?

Comment: I'd never heard of the game so the tag didn't jump out at me, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Non heros join a town randomly from those available.
- Heros get to choose what town to join.
- You can't (directly) join advanced towns without 100 SP.

**However**, when you join a city, you drag with you as many available people from your coalition as possible -- regardless of their soul score.

---

This gratuitous formula explains how many soul points you get by surviving for *n* days in a city:

[image: Don't worry.]

See **[the Die2Nite guide](http://www.die2nite.com/#help/death_and_soul_points?search=soul;sk=aefb0)** for more, especially on the meaning of the term "surviving". There are many corner cases, like death by addiction, that discount your last day.

Comment: Hey! I've got a patent pending on adding superfluous information in order to garner upvotes!

Comment: @Arda http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/281567#281567

Answer (score 2):

They're filled up linearly. People who join in the same time-frame therefore come in the same town.

Once you get 100 soul points, you get to join veteran towns, which have a bigger desert and will only have other people with 100 soul points. Therefore, once you have survived for a full 14 days **in the same town**, you get to join a town with experienced people only.

Of course, when you're a Hero, you get to decide for yourself which town you'd like to join.

So no, they're not secretly skill-matching. They are doing it in a very obvious way.

If you're interested, the formula for soul points is [image: 0.5(n+n^2)] where n is the amount of days you lived **fully** in a particular town. Basically, you add up the amount of days, which means that by day 14 you'll have 1+2+...+14 = 105 soul points.

Comment: But if they match by time, then people who die overnight (and hence have a little more experience) will mostly rejoin straight after, creating the town like my second. Interesting.

Comment: When Gnome and I were joining our 100+SP town, there were two 100+ towns filling simultaneously.  Two people joined about 5 minutes before us and were put in one of them, and then Gnome and I were put in another.  So I don't think it is quite linear.